# How to get the name of FormControl in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

I have two dropdown with multiselect.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [formControl]="FirstFormControl" multiple>
    <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selectA($event) *ngFor="let msj of filter?.msj" [value]=msj>{{msj}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>



 <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="SecondFormControl" multiple>
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selectB($event) *ngFor="let guide of filter?.guide" [value]=guide>{{guide}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

In Typescript I need to know which is the name of FormControl that is clicked because I want to make different things in both cases.

```
FirstFormControl = new FormControl();
SecondFormControl = new FormControl();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the `formcontrol` name manually from template to your component method

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [formControl]="SecondFormControl" multiple>
        <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selectB($event, 'SecondFormControl') *ngFor="let guide of filter?.guide" [value]=guide>{{guide}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

ts code:

```
selectB(event, cntrlName){
  console.log(cntrlName);
  console.log(this.myForm.get(cntrlName).value);
}
```

Alternatively you can observe form control [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges) for each form control and get its name